# How to add event listeners to elements that are inside one another

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick, dom-events, onclicklistener

This image is to explain what my problems is:

[image]

I have a Detail-box and I have added the "click" event listener to it. I want to jump to another page when anyone clicks this link.
Also, I what to add "click" event-listener to the button inside this box (for doing some other action).

The problem is
whenever I click on the button the event-listener corresponding to the the box runs and the event-listener corresponding to the button does not.

How do I solve this problem?
Any help would be great.

Comment: well black font on black background isnt the best choice

Comment: Please consider creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for us.

Comment: @Ifaruki, you might be using dark mode. The image is fine i think.

Comment: I will make sure next time, thanks @SMAMSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for `event.stopPropagation()` event property.

[MDN Documentation link on Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gcLsrfew/)

```
const detailsAlert = e => {
    alert('details alert!');
}

const buttonAlert = e => {
e.stopPropagation();
alert('button alert!');
}

document.getElementById("details").addEventListener('click', detailsAlert, false)

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', buttonAlert, false);
```

Comment: thanks @Altair312, it worked,you just saved the day.

Comment: I also tried to change the z-index so that the buttons are above the details box, but it didn't work. What could be the reason.

Comment: @harsh_joyeit it was my first guess to also think that it would work by changing Z-Indexes, but JavaScript, it seems, propagates events to their parents, unless otherwise stated, as I showed you above with stopPropagation().